# Three.js delete LOD in Group

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a THREE.Group() and in it are alot of LODs and i want to get rid of all the objects in this group. There are Lights, LensFlare, other Groups, Points, Lines and Meshs inside. Like 350 of them.

```
systemGroup.traverse (function (obj){
    systemGroup.remove(obj);
});
```

It removes 175 of it and after that i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'traverse' of undefined
```

for the line one in my example code here.

I also tried

```
scene.remove(systemGroup);
```

Which works well but when i fill my group with other objects, the old ones are still there.
I want everthing to be gone in this group to start like from the beginning. Also for performance because i want to fill it often with lots of stuff.

Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 0):

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'traverse' of undefined"`

It looks like systemGroup is not defined in the context you are calling this from.

Check where systemGroup is defined, what context you are calling systemGroup.traverse from, and also your spelling/capitalization.  If none of that works you might need to post your full code to get a valuable answer.

Comment: the complete code is like 4000 rows and for the half of the group it works but then it stops and gives this error. Maybe i can come up tomorrow with an example code and the error in it which is smaller.

Comment: Alright, good idea.  Comment here again if you get around to doing that.